# A trouble with where and if expressions

Tags: haskell

I wonder, why doesn't this work (2 erros):

```
removeCard cardList card e =
  if length $ (filter` cardList) == (length cardList)
  -- the same error 
  -- if length $ filter` cardList == length cardList
  -- if (length $ filter` cardList) == (length cardList)
  then error "The error occured"
  else filter` cardList
  where
    filter` [] = []
    filter` (x:xs) = if x == card then xs else x : filter` xs
```

If I just replace if with a simple expression with like `if 1 == 2 ...`, I'll get another error:

```
 parse error on input `where'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a backtick in name for "filter prime". Use a single quote instead:

```
  removeCard cardList card e =
    if length (filter' cardList) == (length cardList)
    -- the same error
    -- if length $ filter' cardList == length cardList
    -- if (length $ filter' cardList) == (length cardList)
    then error "The error occured"
    else filter' cardList
    where
      filter' [] = []
      filter' (x:xs) = if x == card then xs else x : filter' xs
```

Backticks are used to indicate infix notation for non-symbolic function names.

Answer (score 2):

Backticks (`) are not legal characters in identifiers. They are used to write ordinary binary functions as infix operators, as in

```
(== card) `filter` cardList
```

You probably wanted to use primes (').

```
removeCard cardList card e =
  if length $ (filter' cardList) == (length cardList)
  then error "The error occured"
  else filter' cardList
  where
    filter' [] = []
    filter' (x:xs) = if x == card then xs else x : filter' xs
```